# Determine the fastest unsigned integer type for basic arithmetic calculations

Tags: c

I'm writing some code for calculating with arbitrarily large unsigned integers. This is just for fun and training, otherwise I'd use *libgmp*. My representation uses an array of unsigned integers and for chosing the "base type", I use a typedef:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef unsigned int hugeint_Uint;

typedef struct hugeint hugeint;

#define HUGEINT_ELEMENT_BITS (CHAR_BIT * sizeof(hugeint_Uint))
#define HUGEINT_INITIAL_ELEMENTS (256 / HUGEINT_ELEMENT_BITS)

struct hugeint
{
    size_t s;         // <- maximum number of elements
    size_t n;         // <- number of significant elements
    hugeint_Uint e[]; // <- elements of the number starting with least significant
};
```

The code is working fine, so I only show the part relevant to my question here.

I would like to pick a better "base type" than `unsigned int`, so the calculations are the fastest possible on the target system (e.g. a 64bit type when targeting x86_64, a 32bit type when targeting i686, an 8bit type when targeting avr_attiny, ...)

I *thought* that `uint_fast8_t` should do what I want. But I found out it doesn't, see e.g. here the relevant part of `stdint.h` from MinGW:

```
/*  7.18.1.3  Fastest minimum-width integer types
 *  Not actually guaranteed to be fastest for all purposes
 *  Here we use the exact-width types for 8 and 16-bit ints.
 */
typedef signed char int_fast8_t;
typedef unsigned char uint_fast8_t;
```

The comment is interesting: for which purpose would an `unsigned char` be faster than an `unsigned int` on win32? Well, the important thing is: `uint_fast8_t` will not do what I want.

So is there some good and portable way to find the fastest unsigned integer type?

Comment: Sure there is - testing.

Comment: @ThingyWotsit obviously. So I should have asked instead whether testing/measuring is indeed the *only* reasonable way?

Comment: `uint_fast8_t` **is** certainly the fastest for a _single_ 8-bit operation but this task uses an array of `hugeint_Uint`.  With `uint_fast8_t` or `uint_fast16_t` or `uint_fast32_t` or `uint_fast64_t`, OP's code needs  8x, or 4x or 2x or 1x number of elements to the `hugeint_Uint e[];` and it is the _product_ of the _single_ type's performance and the number needed, that determines performance.

Comment: IMO, the fastest size for "arbitrarily large unsigned integers" will use an element size that is `unsigned` or 1/2 the width of `unsigned`.  Yet without sample code, that opinion lacks a test case.  By using `uintmax_t` I see the carry detection of `a+b` and `a*b` code is likely inefficient as well as the chain division.

Comment: @chux the whole code [is here](https://github.com/Zirias/hugeint) -- as I already said *just for fun and training* and I asked for reviews over at *codereview* with a lot of great input -- I just wanted to ask this specific question about the "best" base type separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not quite that black and white; processors may have different/specialized registers for certain operations, like AVX registers on x86_64, may operate most efficiently on half-sized registers or not have registers at all. The choice of the "fastest integer type" thus depends heavily on the actual calculation you need to perform.

Having said that, C99 defines `uintmax_t` which is meant to represent the maximum width unsigned integer type, but beware, it could be 64 bit simply because the compiler is able to *emulate* 64-bit math.

If you target commodity processors, `size_t` usually provides a good approximation for the *"bitness"* of the underlying hardware because it is directly tied to the memory addressing capability of the machine, and as such is most likely to be the most optimal size for integer math.

In any case you're going to have to *test* your solution on all hardware that you're planning to support.

Comment: In particular the fastest type for multi-word integer arithmetic depends on the arithmetic operation being performed. For instance addition is likely efficient `uintmax_t` in units whereas efficient multiplication typically requires double-word intermediate operations (or manual splitting, which amounts to the same thing). Also beware that `uintmax_t` is frequently wholly or partially simulated type with limited native support, for instance on common 32-bit x86/ARM compilers a generic division of 64-bit `uintmax_t` types shunts of to costly CRT helper functions.

Comment: Accepting this answer as my measurement seems to confirm `uintmax_t` being a good choice. Calculating the factorial of 10000 takes ca 12,3s on my win10 machine here with `unsigned int` and only 11,7s with `uintmax_t`. Surprisingly, it has no effect whether compiling for win32 or win64.

Comment: Disagree that "On commodity processors this (`uintmax_t`) should give the best approximation for the "bitness" of the underlying hardware.".  `uintmax_t` must be at least 64-bits regardless if the underlying hardware is 8,16,32 or 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good idea to *start* your code with the largest integer type the platform has, `uintmax_t`. As has already been pointed out, this is not *necessarily*, but rather *most probably* the fastest. I'd rather say there are *exceptions* where this is not the case, but as a default, it is probably your best bet.

Be very careful to build the size granularity into expressions that the compiler can resolve at *compile type*, rather than *runtime* for speed.

It is most probably a good idea to define the base type as something like

```
#define LGINT_BASETYPE uintmax_t
#define LGINT_GRANUL   sizeof(LGINT_BASETYPE)
```

This will allow you to change the base type in one single place and adapt to different platforms quickly. That results in code that is easily moved to a new platform, but still can be adapted to the exception cases where the largest int type is not the most performant one (after you have proven that by measurement)

As always, it does not make a lot of sense to think about optimal performance when designing your code - Start with a reasonable balance of "designed for optimization" and "design for maintainability" - You might easily find out that the choice of base type is not really the most CPU-eating part of your code. In my experience, I was nearly *always* in for some surprises when comparing my *guesses* on where CPU is spent to my *measurements*. Don't fall into the premature optimization trap.